# micronaut RxWebSocketClient how to dynamically connect to a client?

Tags: micronaut

[@Client("http://localhost:8082")](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-vuejs-cqrs/blob/master/hotel-write/src/main/java/hotel/write/event/listeners/KafkaEventListener.java#L41-L45) I have the following declaration on this bit of the code on link provided:

```
/**
 * TODO this is currently hard wired to something that is dynamic in command object host/port
 */
@Inject
@Client("http://localhost:8082")
RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient;
```

There is a [segment of code](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-vuejs-cqrs/blob/master/hotel-write/src/main/java/hotel/write/event/listeners/KafkaEventListener.java#L136-L137) much further down:

```
 ChatClientWebSocket chatClient = webSocketClient.connect(ChatClientWebSocket.class, "/ws/process").blockingFirst();
                    chatClient.send(serializeMessage(msg));
```

Ideally I would like to define to which client based on existing data within the [command object](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-vuejs-cqrs/blob/master/gateway-command/src/main/java/gateway/command/event/commands/Command.java#L20-L21) :

```
 private String host;
    private int port;
```

In above class the host port is generated by this microservice itself which in for the purpose of testing is physically bound but assuming it dynamically came up on different ports `127.0.0.1:8083` and `127.0.0.1:8084` and so on how can the dynamic host port declare what is declared at the top i.e.

```
@Client("http://localhost:8082")
```

Ideally what I need to be able to do is something like this
So the client connection is dynamic based on the current object host port definition rather than hard coded at the top of the page which is outside of where dynamics takes place..

```
                @Client(cmd.getHost()+":"+cmd.getPort())
                RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient;
                ChatClientWebSocket chatClient = webSocketClient.connect(ChatClientWebSocket.class, "/ws/process").blockingFirst();
                chatClient.send(serializeMessage(msg));
```

Comment: "Ideally I would like to define to which client based on existing data within the command object define which is represented as msg in the code." - I don't understand what you mean by that.  There is only 1 client represented in your code and it isn't clear what your command object contains.

Comment: I have updated question hopefully will make more sense

Answer (score 0):

You can try use property:

```java
@Client("${myapp.api.twitter.url}")
RxWebSocketClient webSocketClient;
```

Comment: Thanks I think that still leaves how I would assign a dynamic variable to it much further nested in the code. Slightly off topic but still related. This concept changed and I am no longer using but https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-vuejs-cqrs/blob/master/gateway-command/src/main/java/gateway/command/event/http/HttpEventPublisher.java#L20 something like this with another class that  passes @Client bit as it calls above doing above work https://github.com/vahidhedayati/micronaut-vuejs-cqrs/blob/master/gateway-command/src/main/java/gateway/command/event/http/HotelListener.java#L43

Comment: I think that there are not dynamic clients, different clients used... if i understand what you mean

Comment: In my case it was yes - I was meant to have gone back to it and found an easier way I think https://guides.micronaut.io/micronaut-http-client/guide/index.html under section 4 public `BintrayLowLevelClient(@Client(BintrayConfiguration.BINTRAY_API_URL) RxHttpClient httpClient`, could be  `public BintrayLowLevelClient(RxHttpClient httpClient,` and perhaps either extended class or another class calling would call the method and provide the @Client bit with the overridden RxHttpClient that it passes in - if that makes any sense - theoretical stuff none practised that may hit a big brick wall

Comment: `@Client(BintrayConfiguration.BINTRAY_API_URL)` in this case `BintrayConfiguration.BINTRAY_API_URL` it is just constant variable, about `BintrayLowLevelClient ` yes you expand this class and path any `Client` to the `fetchPackages()`,  by the way you have to define differents `Clients` before for expanded `BintrayLowLevelClient`, I mean it is also not dynamic `one` client, it is can be several predefined `Clients` which you can then path to the exanded `BintrayLowLevelClient `